# svglib - Convert SVG to PNG with a transparent background?

Tags: python, svg, png

I am utilizing svglib and report lab to convert an SVG file to a PNG file.

`renderPM.drawToFile(drawing, png_file_path, fmt="PNG", configPIL={'transparent': None})`

And it works to convert the file, unfortunately the background of the image is not transparent.

I have tried adding a colour to the transparent attribute of the configPIL and making it transparent that way, but it seems to not affect the background at all.

How can I convert from SVG to PNG with a transparent background using python?

Comment: https://github.com/deeplook/svglib/issues/171#issuecomment-457604019

Comment: Check out https://cairosvg.org/documentation/

Comment: I found a workaround by rendering to pdf first with `svglib` and then using `pymupdf` which doesn't need any external libraries as it comes with precompiled wheels. [See my stackoverflow answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74164750/1506569)